# SQL: String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

This worked in the very same manner last week. Today when I am trying to insert the data again, it gives me this silly error. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check for a trigger (or perhaps default constraint?) which looks to be trying to populate the `DW_LAST_MODIFIED_BY` column with more than 25 characters.